# Getting error {missing_app_file,.. on rebar get-deps

Tags: erlang, rebar

I set-up some dependencies in my rebar.config (which I have done previously in other projects)

rebar.config:

```
{sub_dirs, ["sbin", "priv"]}.
{lib_dirs, ["deps/erlang"]}.
{erl_opts, [{parse_transform, lager_transform}]}.
{eunit_opts, [verbose, {report,{eunit_surefire,[{dir,"."}]}}]}.
{cover_enabled, true}.
{cover_export_enabled, true}.
{deps, [
{lager, "2.0.3",
    {git, "git://github.com/basho/lager.git", {tag, "2.0.3"}}},
{ezk, ".*",
    {git, "git@github.com:campanja/ezk.git"}}
]}.
```

When I run rebare get-deps I am getting the following errors:

```
ERROR: Dependency dir /Users/me/workspace/erlang/try-ezk/deps/ezk failed application validation with reason:
{missing_app_file,"/Users/me/workspace/erlang/try-ezk/deps/ezk"}.
ERROR: 'get-deps' failed while processing /Users/me/workspace/erlang/try-ezk: rebar_abort
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong this time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try with this syntax:

```
{ezk, ".*",{git, "git://github.com/campanja/ezk.git"}}
```

Comment: To @jgritty, I know the syntax I propose is correct, but this does not imply that the other one was not. So there were no evidence that it will solve the issue, and it is why I ask to try.